# C++ DLL Class is crashing whilst creating a private member

Tags: c++, class, dll, crash

I have a Problem and i am completely stuck.

First i show you the code:

Config for Building(NarviConfig.h):

```
#pragma once;
namespace Narvi
{
#ifdef NARVI_EXPORTS
#define _NarviExport __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define _NarviExport __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
}
```

//-------------------------------------------

I have 2 Classes in a DLL like this:

The first One(NarviRoot.h):

Header:

```
#pragma once

#include "NarviConfig.h"
#include "NarviWindow.h"

namespace Narvi
{
    class _NarviExport NarviRoot
    {
    public:
         NarviRoot();
         ~NarviRoot();
    public:
         bool Init(void);
    private:
        NarviWindow* mWindow;
    };
}
```

Source:-----------------------------

```
#include "NarviRoot.h"

namespace Narvi
{
    NarviRoot::NarviRoot()
    {
    }


    NarviRoot::~NarviRoot()
    {
            delete mWindow;
    }

    bool NarviRoot::Init(void)
    {
        mWindow = new NarviWindow();
        return true;
    }
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------

The window(NarviWindow.h):

Header

```
#pragma once
#include "NarviConfig.h"

namespace Narvi
{
    class _NarviExport NarviWindow
    {
    public:
        NarviWindow();
        ~NarviWindow();

    };
}
```

Source:--------------------------------

```
#include "NarviWindow.h"    
namespace Narvi
{
    NarviWindow::NarviWindow()
    {
    }


    NarviWindow::~NarviWindow()
    {

    }
}
```

And this is my Testapp

```
mRoot = new Narvi::NarviRoot();
mRoot->Init();
```

It seems to work, but the program crashes  when calling

```
mWindow = new NarviWindow();
```

Inside of

```
bool NarviRoot::Init(void)
{
        mWindow = new NarviWindow();
        return true;
}
```

and i can't figure out why.

If i write:

```
  NarviWindow* mWindow = new NarviWindow();
```

it doesn't crash.

The constructor of NarviWindow is doing nothing, but it seems he can't access the private member mWindow.

I am pretty sure it is a simple error i made, but i can't see the wood for the trees.

Thank you! :)

Comment: what is the exact message of crash?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x0FC7C308 (Narvi.dll) in TestApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.  The mWindow is only being used in NarviRoot, it should not be accessible from outside.

Comment: Seems clear from the error message that mRoot is NULL. Why that should be I have no idea but maybe you could test that theory.

Comment: Ohhh. Wood for the Trees...I found the Problem. mRoot is NULL. It was never created, since the method, which creates the object was never called. =D I feeeel soo bad. Thank you John. Thank you soo much!